# TStringGrid doesn't recognize VK_DELETE as a keypress

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

I have a number of TStringGrids inside TTab's and have been using
if (Key==VK_RETURN) for years (its an old app) as the trigger to execute code pertaining the the cell entry.

I would now like the option to delete the Cell contents, by writing a empty string to it, so tried using 
if (Key==VK_DELETE)

yet the Delete Button does not trigger the OnKeyPress event at all in my case.

I was hoping to capture the event via the following code pertaining to the specific active Stringrid1

```
void __fastcall TPagesDlgLoadEditorFixed::StringGrid1KeyPress(TObject 
*Sender, char &Key)
{
   int Grid = 1;
   EntriesOnStringGrid(Key, Grid);
}
```

and with the KeyPress then passed on code that is common to all the StringGrids, as follows:

```
void TPagesDlgLoadEditorFixed::EntriesOnStringGrid(char &Key, int Grid)
{

 if (Key==VK_RETURN)
 {
   //code works fine
 }
 if (Key==VK_DELETE)
 {
   //code has no effect
 }

}
```

However whilst in debug mode, one can see that the StringGrid1KeyPress event is not triggered at all by the "Delete" button.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is the VCL, you should use the OnKeyUp and OnKeyDown events rather than the OnKeyPress event for most non-alphanumeric keys.

Comment: `VK_DELETE` is a *virtual* key code. The `OnKeyPress` event delivers *translated* keys instead.  You need to use the `OnKey(Down|Up)` events to handle virtual keys. You should read ["A Key’s Odyssey"](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447) on EDN for detailed information about how the VCL processes key strokes from the OS.

Comment: Many thanks to both Rudy and Remi. In the end I needed to use OnKeyUp for the VK_DELETE code to activate and OnKeyPress for the VK_RETURN code to activate, so a little bit of duplication, but it all works now, thanks. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's generally better to use `OnKeyUp` and `OnKeyDown` when checking for virtual key codes instead of `OnKeyPress`.

So using that should fix your problem and then it will detect `VK_DELETE` when it's pressed or let go.